# Htaccess, redirect exepted some dmains

Tags: .htaccess

I am a beginner and I coded a hataccess that works as I want on my site but can not redirect to an external site like facebook twitter or linked. Can you help me please. Thank you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I m studid !

The .htaccess works fine, the problem was my links, the protocol was missing !!!!